# How to identify the sender of a WM_COMMAND message?

Tags: visual-c++, wm-command

I am using VS 2010 c++.  I have a dialog window containing an array of 126 identical pushbutton controls sharing the same value for control ID.
When a button is clicked and the host dialog window receives the resulting WM_COMMAND message, how can the dialog window identify which pushbutton is pressed?
I could use 126 different control ID values, but I was hoping for something a little more concise.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

ID itself means "what identifies" an object. So you will need to have separate control ID.

There has to be something different about each button control to identify a particular one.

If you want to keep the same control ID, then you can keep track of the handle (HWND) of each button that is created and use the LPARAM parameter of WM_COMMAND message to identify the control by handle.

If you are having unique text for each button then you can use the text property also of the button.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate response.  Shortly after posting this question, I stumbled upon BN_CLICKED on the msdn website, which led me to the answer you posted re hPB == HIWORD(lParam).